# Angular6 - HttpClient error handling of GET net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular, http, error-handling

In Angular6 using the HttpClient, is there anyway to catch the GET net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error/exception?  For typical http requests I usually see a single error/exception of Type HttpErrorResponse...for example, a 404 Not Found.  However, for certain http requests where either the port or the remote service is not there and network issues, I see 2 errors/exceptions in the browser console :

a.) GET https://localhost:8443/sb-template/status-routes net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED { ... }

and then a second one that my code is catching :

b.) HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

So, I'm able to easily catch/capture display the contents from the second error, HttpErrorResponse.  But is there anyway to catch/capture the initial error instead...

The reasons here are the message in the second error (HttpErrorResponse), is very generic and reveals very little : Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error...this could be from any number of issues.

But if I can catch/capture the initial error...specifically net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, this provides more important information on a possible port or remote service being down.

Comment: Console log details are based on the response browser emitting it. You have to just handle the HttpErrorResponse based on status code.

Comment: Ok, good to know.  So the status code is 0 (zero).  So does a 0 indicate no port open and/or the URL resource is not available?  Or is it that since the URL gave no response, the status never gets set?

Answer (score 0):

Chromium network error code list can checked using `chrome://network-errors/`. Console log error code details is emitted by chrome browser. You just need to handle HttpErrorResponse and set the error message based on status code.

Status code zero may returned due to chrome adblocker or invalid authentication /cert details or  [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue. If you have access to server api then set following property for response header which allows server to accept the request even request come from different origin.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

[*] enable cross origin requests from anywhere. this can be restricted to specific domain or requested origin. request.getHeader("Origin")

Comment: I added the CORS to the micro-service controller in Spring Boot, but it had no effect, so it's probably got to be the Chrome preventing the status code from coming thru.  I'll need to dive deeper, but for now, I'll just have to live with this and "assume" that status-code=0 is a network issue.  TY!

Comment: In case of a status-code=0 how would you get angular to navigate to a 404 not found page/component on the front end. this.router.navigate does not seem to work for me. @nayakam

Comment: @Daybreak status-code = 0 means request is cancelled before get the response due to network error. Mostly due to CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Status code 0 indicates that the request has not been made, which most typically is a CORS OPTIONS call failing, and since this is handled outside the javascript domain details are not available. Since your error is a GET request I am not sure if this is exactly the same, but for OPTIONS [angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22022) has no extra details.